# Adding Cordova plugins after native build with sencha

Tags: plugins, cordova, build, sencha-touch

I successfully add and then build a Sencha Touch app with Cordova plugins. However, when I decide to add a plugin later and then build again, the build fails. 
Is it so that you add plugins only before running `sencha app build native` or there is another issue. I get the following in console

```
[INF] [shellscript] ** BUILD FAILED **
[INF] [shellscript] 
[INF] [shellscript] 
[INF] [shellscript] The following build commands failed:
[INF] [shellscript]     CompileC build/swigmunk.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/swigmunk.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVCamera.o swigmunk/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera/CDVCamera.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[INF] [shellscript]     CompileC build/swigmunk.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/swigmunk.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVJpegHeaderWriter.o swigmunk/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera/CDVJpegHeaderWriter.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[INF] [shellscript] (2 failures)
[INF] [shellscript] ]
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/georgy/Developer/swigmunk/public/swigmunk/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:422: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/georgy/Developer/swigmunk/public/swigmunk/.sencha/app/cordova-impl.xml:118: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/Users/georgy/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.1.45/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:608: shellscript returned: 1
```

Comment: You'll probably get more info if you execute just the failing commands from the terminal, i.e. `CompileC build/swigmunk.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/swigmunk.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVCamera.o swigmunk/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera/CDVCamera.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler`

Comment: Were you able to fix this is problem? I am facing same problem and there seems to be no solution to this.

Comment: same here, any workaround for this issue?

Comment: I was getting this error because of another error - namely: I couldn't get "cordova platform add android" to work. But after fixing that by making updates to check_reqs.js I was able to then add android and then the command above also worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Cordova plugins anyway and it doesn't seem to work, why don't you skip the native build of sencha and do it all the way with Cordova? Would be an alternative to your approach. To do so, you have to build your sencha project like this:

```
// Good for debugging if sth crashes on devices but not in your Browser
sencha app build testing

// or for production
sencha app build production
```

After you have done that you can see a /testing or /production folder in your project directory. You will need the files inside to be copied into your Cordova project.

To get this working with Cordova, you have to create a Cordova project, like explained in the [docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html). If you have done that, you can just copy your build Sencha project into the www folder of your Cordova project and execute:

```
cordova prepare [your platform]
```

This command copies the www files into your native project and you can execute it with Eclipse for Android and xCode for iOS. If you have added a plugin you need to run:

```
cordova prepare [your platform]
cordova compile [your platform]
```

This command will copy the www-stuff and also build the native code which comes from your plugin.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just went through the same issue and I solved it by removing all platforms (just iOS in my case) and adding them again after installing the new plugin.

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios
```

That should do it

Comment: Confirmed working for me. My environment was spun up by another developer, so this may have been caused by not calling the `cordova platform add ios` locally.